# .get() function to get firebase docs "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hey I am trying to get all documents of a certain collection in firebase using:

```
const userCollectionRef = collection(db, currentUser?.uid)
const snapshot = await userCollectionRef.get()
for (const doc of snapshot) {
    console.log(doc.id)
}
```

The problem:

```
TypeError: userCollectionRef.get is not a function
```

My imports:

```
import { db } from '../firebase'
import { collection } from 'firebase/firestore'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a top-level function [`getDocs()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#getdocs) that you can use to fetch multiple documents using a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) in V9 SDK:

```
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const userCollectionRef = collection(db, currentUser?.uid)

const snapshot = await getDocs(userCollectionRef)

const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) for more information.